# No screen when drawing using turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a square using turtle in python however its not opening any screen.

There are no errors on the shell. I am using python 2.7 on windows 7

Here is the code I am using:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("green")
    mark = turtle.Turtle()
    mark.forward(100)
    mark.right(90)
    mark.forward(100)
    mark.right(90)
    mark.forward(100)
    mark.right(90)
    mark.forward(100)
    mark.right(90)
    window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You need to call `draw_square`

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you! Seems like the code is running but not drawing anything visually. The shell output says

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>>

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I came onto the forum looking for the exact same answer for the Udacity course. I don't know why, but the problem is in the def line.  If you cancel it out and remove the indents, it runs fine. I'm running 2.7 on a Macbook.

import turtle

# 
def draw_square():

window = turtle.Screen()

window.bgcolor (“red")

brad = turtle.Turtle()
brad.right (10)

window.exitonclick()